# Erlang simple server problem

Tags: erlang

As I learn Erlang, I'm trying to solve ex. 4.1 ("An Echo server") from "Erlang Programming" book (by O'Reilly) and I have a problem.
My code looks like that:

```
-module(echo).
-export([start/0, print/1, stop/0, loop/0]).

start() ->
    register(echo, spawn(?MODULE, loop, [])),
    io:format("Server is ready.~n").

loop() ->
    receive
        {print, Msg} ->
            io:format("You sent a message: ~w.~n", [Msg]),
            start();
        stop ->
            io:format("Server is off.~n");
        _ ->
            io:format("Unidentified command.~n"),
            loop()
    end.

print(Msg) -> ?MODULE ! {print, Msg}.

stop() -> ?MODULE ! stop.
```

Unfortunatelly, I have some problems. Turning on works as expected, it spawns a new process and display "Server is ready" message. But when I try to use print function (like `echo:print("Some message.").` that, for example) I got result, but it doesn't work like I'd like to. It prints my message as a list (not as a string) and it generates

```
=ERROR REPORT==== 18-Jul-2010::01:06:27 ===
Error in process <0.89.0> with exit value: {badarg,[{erlang,register,[echo,<0.93.0>]},{echo,start,0}]}
```

error message.
Moreover, when I try to stop server by `echo:stop()` I got another error

```
** exception error: bad argument
 in function  echo:stop/0
```

Could anybody explain me, what's going on here ? I am new to Erlang and it seems to be quite difficult to grasp for me at this time.

Comment: Strings are represented as lists in erlang.

Comment: Of course you're right, but since there are no characters, that couldn't be displayed, why it displays as a list, not a string ?
But this is just one thing, not the most important, the problem remains the same.

Comment: @Hynek has explained the main problem.

Strings are lists of integers, so `"abc"` is the same as `[97,98,99]`. So erlang doesn't really "know" if your list of integers is just a list of integers or a string. Using `~w` in a format string just prints it as a list. If you use `~p`it will test if lists of integers could be printable strings and if so print them as strings. This what the shell does.

Yes, this was intended, no it is not a bug. Having strings as lists makes them very easy to work with.

Comment: Indeed, with ~p parameter, print works just like expected. Thank for this tip.

Answer (score 9):

When your `loop/0` function receive `print` message you call `start/0` again which spawns new process and trying to register it as `echo` again. It causes your server dies and new one is not registered as `echo`, so you can't send message to it by `print/1` function any more.

```
loop() ->
    receive
        {print, Msg} ->
            io:format("You sent a message: ~w.~n", [Msg]),
            loop();   % <-- just here!
        stop ->
            io:format("Server is off.~n");
        _ ->
            io:format("Unidentified command.~n"),
            loop()
    end.
```

Comment: Of course, it was that simple. Thank you very much, it seems that I was tired and didn't notice obvious error. Thank you again.